# Mapping IQueryable where clause from DTO to Entity

Tags: c#, linq, odata, automapper

I've got an OData WebAPI method as follows:

```
        // GET: odata/Employees
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<DTOs.Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        return this.AttemptOperation(context => 
            {
                IQueryable<DTOs.Employee> employees
                    = context.Employees.Project().To<DTOs.Employee>();
                return employees;
            });
    }
```

It returns data to to the service if I don't specify a filter.
But as soon as I add $filter=EmployeeID eq '1' to the URL I get an exception.

The exception is from an AWS DynamoDB context library I use for performing LINQ queries against DynamoDB.  However, what it is indicating is that the context doesn't have a table for DTOs.Employee.

This of course is obvious, the context has the entities, not the DTOs.

How can I get the IQueryable where clause specified from the client to translate back to the proper entity type?

For example, the client needs to query against DTOs.Employee.EmployeeID and it needs to translate into a where clause against Entities.Employee.EmployeeID.

Comment: This is odd, I remember we doing something exactly like this and it worked as expected. Could you perhaps test this using a simple Entity Framework mapped model and compare it to the same model in DynamoDB? I suspect this could be caused by some particularity in DynamoDB's queryable provider. Also, is that really a `GetEmployee` method? The code implies it is a `GetEmployees` like call. And I assume it is not really relevant, but was is that `AttemptOperation` call doing?

Comment: You are right, its employees... it will likely get renamed, I started from a visual studio template and haven't looked into the naming conventions yet as I'm just trying to get things working.

Hmm, I will have to check the Linq2DynamoDB's IQueryable provider.  I already worked with the code maintainer in fixing code earlier today that prevented the projection from working in one direction.

AttemptOperation builds the context and does error handling, I wrap all WebApi and MVC methods in that pattern.

Comment: I just dug into the provider to see where its blowing up.  Its walking the expression tree of the where clause and comparing the entity type of the table (Entities.Employee) against the MemberExpression which has an Expression.Type value of (DTOs.Employee).  Maybe its just me, but I would expect the data provider to receive a query against its native type.

Does AutoMapper convert the where clause of IQueryable from one type or another? Or is that a misunderstanding on my side?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. You should probably try to talk to Jimmy himself about this. I still suspect it's an implementation detail that is not agreeing with the DynamoDB layer, but I wouldn't know exactly what it's doing really. You could try posting this as an issue in the AutoMapper issue tracker and point to here so that Jim can provide an answer (and perhaps fix it if it is a problem on his tool). Also I just noticed that you didn't tag the question with AutoMapper... will edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
public IQueryable<DTOs.Employee> GetEmployees()
{
    return this.AttemptOperation(context => 
        {
            // I commented here your old code:
            // IQueryable<DTOs.Employee> employees = context.Employees.Project().To<DTOs.Employee>();

            // This is our new code:
            var employees = context.Employees.Project()

            return employees.select(m=> new EmployeeDto {
                property1 = m.property1,
                property2 = m.property2
            }
        });
}
```

**Important**: You cannot use an EmployeeDto constructor. It is forbidden to do so under Linq.